# setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); não funciona no Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, c++

Boa noite a todos,

Fiz muita pesquisa sobre como resolver a problema de acentuação da língua portuguesa que ocorreu logo depois de atualizar para windows 10 mas sem sucesso até o momento. vou postar o meu código aqui para análise, quero muito resolver este problema se puder me ajudar eu agradeço imensamente.
[image: o modelo do projeto que sempre utilizo para praticar]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    //Declaração das variáveis.
    int getch(void);
    int indice=0;
    float media;
    char nome[40];
    char letra = 's';
    float nota[3];
  
    //Inicializando as variáveis.
    media = 0;
   
    while (letra == 's' || letra == 'S')
    {
        _locale_t _get_current_locale(void);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, ".OCP");
        printf("Nome do %d aluno é: ",indice+1);
        rewind(stdin);
        gets_s(nome);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            printf("\nDigite a %d nota: ",i+1);
            scanf_s("%f", &nota[i]); 
        }
        media = (nota[0] + nota[1] + nota[2]) / 3;
        indice++;

        printf("\nA media do aluno %s eh: %.2f", nome, media);
        printf("\n\nDeseja consulta a nota do proximo aluno (s/n)? ");
        rewind(stdin);
        letra = _getche();
        system("cls");

    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Não há nada na atualização para o Windows 10 que vá criar problemas com acentos.
Na verdade desde 2018 Windows 10 tem o Terminal que é o local certo para rodar programas de console desde então: acentos, Unicode, grego, russo, Unicode com todos os símbolos possíveis. E aceleração gráfica usando a placa de vídeo. E True Color ao invés de 256 cores.

Não entendi seu programa. a "muita pesquisa" que fez incluiu esse endereço: [Documentação oficial sobre a console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) e talvez esse link, que está em toda tela de console do Windows 10: [novos recursos da console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/) e esse [Configurações experimentais do terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.11/mt427362(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image: Nas propriedades da janela]

### De volta ao seu programa

```
        _locale_t _get_current_locale(void);
```

Sempre que você roda um programa na console e muda algo é ético e educado copiar a configuração original e restaurar na saída. E isso inclui o locale, as páginas de código, as fontes e, claro, as cores. Por um momento achei que estava fazendo isso mas não salvou em lugar nenhum então de nada serviu. Leu a documentação sobre `_get_current_locale()` retornar um `_locale_t` ? E o que fez com ele? Nada. Não declarou nenhum.

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, ".OCP");
```

Isso provavelmente não é uma boa idéia. É como chamar `system()` para fazer algo. Se você tem um problema com `locale` muda o `locale`. com `setlocale()`. Se precisa de uma determinada codepage usa `SetConsoleOutputCP()` e configura a página que quer. Antes, claro, use `GetConsoleOutputCP()` e salve a página em uso e restaure na saída. Seu programa pode deixar alguém bem contrariado se não fizer isso.

Esse comando que usou define o `locale` como sendo o que está configurado no painel de controle.  Mas você sabe qual é? O normal é 850 e não vai servir. Porque não usa o normal `"pt_BR.UTF-8"`?

E no programa, está usando C++, porque não faz o simples e escreve

```
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
```

Que é a página normal aqui no BR? Ou a 65001, Unicode?

Que pretende com

```
        rewind(stdin);
```

Isso quase nunca funciona. Está lendo do teclado.

```
        letra = _getche();
```

Para que isso? O IDE já para sózinho no final do programa. Essa rotina é dos anos 80. Esta compilando um `header` derivado de uma biblioteca da Borland, dos anos 80, apenas para ler uma letrinha? Não precisa disso.

```
        system("cls");
```

E `system()` para limpar a tela é pouco útil porque assim que você teclar algo no IDE ele vai fechar a janela então não faz diferença se limpou a tela ou não. E essa rotina é proibida e perseguida em muitos lugares por questões de segurança.

#### Uma implementação de cls() no oficial

```
 int            cls()
{   // limpa a tela no windows, do jeito oficial
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO      info;
    HANDLE      H = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD       origem = { 0,0 };
    int         total;
    if (H == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return -1;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(H, &info);
    int r = FillConsoleOutputCharacter(H, (TCHAR)' ',
        info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
        origem, &total);
    int s = FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        H, info.wAttributes,
        info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
        origem, &total);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(H, origem);
    return 0;
};  // end cls()
```

O normal dos programas de console no Windows: pega um Handle pra acessar a janela, vê a cor e o tipo de letra em uso, e limpa todo o buffer --- o padrão é de 9001 linhas no Windows há décadas --- e depois coloca o cursor no começo da tela

Answer (score -4):

```
#include <locale.h>

main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt-BR");
...
```